# How can I search for the largest image file in a folder? (resolution and size)

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, images, picasa, file-search

I have a large collection of image files, from different cameras, phones, etc. They are all nicely sorted into folders by date/subject (eg: 2011-12-25-Family Christmas Dinner) and I manage them using Picasa, which is doing quite a great job actually. Picasa lets me search by name, date, or (file)size within a folder, and by color for all images.

Now I would like to search by the following criteria for example:

- the 10 pictures with the largest resolution (recursively in all directories)
- the 10 largest images (filesize, in all directories)
- "similar" images (all directories)
- etc.

I've found ImgSeek, and works for the similar images, but I couldn't find anything for searching the other criteria... Any suggestions?

Comment: Which OS and version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given Windows 7, you should be able to do most of what you want in Windows Explorer.

1. Browse to the top-level folder, and in the search box in the top-right-hand corner type in `name:*` and press Enter (or just wait).  That will find all images recursively.
2. From the view (menu or dropdown) select `Details`
3. Right-click the header of the file list (the bar with 'Name', 'Date', etc in it), and select the fields you want to sort by; for example you could select:

   1. `Horizontal resolution` and `Vertical resolution` to sort by image resolution (dpi)
   2. `Height` and `Width` to sort by pixel size
   3. Size to sort by file size
   4. Exposure time to sort by, well, exposure time (there are other similar EXIF properties also)

...etc.
Note that Windows 7 also allows you to filter by any of those fields by clicking on the arrow to the right of the header field.

Comment: right, completely forgot about that. Probably because I'm not used to viewing my photos with Explorer. Thanks for the tip!